# how to join two X-Y plots held in two ndarrys optimally

Tags: numpy, dygraphs

I want to join two XY plots that can differ in the X axis.
The plots are held in numpy ndarrys and i want the join operation to be optimal, performance wise (i know how to solve this with associative arrays).

the joint operation definition is `PlotAB = join_op(PlotA,PlotB)`:

```
PlotA = 
array([[2, 5],
       [3, 5],
       [5, 5])
```

where `plotA[:,0]` is the X-axis & `plotA[:,1]` is the Y-axis

```
PlotB = 
array([[1, 7],
       [2, 7],
       [3, 7],
       [4, 7]])
```

where `plotB[:,0]` is the X-axis & `plotB[:,1]` is the Y-axis

the joined array is:

```
PlotsAB = 
array([[1, n, 7],
       [2, 5, 7],
       [3, 5, 7],
       [4, n, 7],
       [5, 5, n]])
```

where 
`PlotAB[:,0]` is the joind X-axis (sort uniuq).

`plotAB[:,1]` is the Y-axis of PlotA.

`plotAB[:,2]` is the Y-axis of PlotB.

the `'n'` represent places where a value is missing - not present in this plot.

btw, i need this to compose data for a dygraphs ploter (http://dygraphs.com/gallery/#g/independent-series)

Please advise,
Thanks.

Comment: Are the inputs sorted by first column (X-axis)? Would the output be constructed by keeping the first column(X-axis) sorted? Or are we going with Y-axis being sorted for the first two questions just asked? Also, would there be duplicate points in either of the PlotA or PlotB?

Comment: X-Axis are sorted for both PlotA & PlotB and the outcome (PlotAB) needs to be sorted on the X-Axis too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses `numpy.setdiff1d` to find the unique x elements in each of the input arrays and `numpy.argsort` to sort the input arrays after the [x, NaN] elements have been inserted into them.

```
import numpy as np

def join_op(a,b):
    ax = a[:,0]
    bx = b[:,0]

    # elements unique to b
    ba_x = np.setdiff1d(bx,ax)

    # elements unique to a
    ab_x = np.setdiff1d(ax,bx)

    ba_y = np.NaN*np.empty(ba_x.shape)
    ab_y = np.NaN*np.empty(ab_x.shape)

    ba = np.array((ba_x,ba_y)).T
    ab = np.array((ab_x,ab_y)).T

    a_new = np.concatenate((a,ba))
    b_new = np.concatenate((b,ab))

    a_sort_idx = np.argsort(a_new[:,0])
    b_sort_idx = np.argsort(b_new[:,0])

    a_new_sorted = a_new[a_sort_idx]
    b_new_sorted = b_new[b_sort_idx]

    b_new_sorted_y = b_new_sorted[:,1].reshape(-1,1)

    return np.concatenate((a_new_sorted,b_new_sorted_y),axis=1)

a = np.array([[2,5],[3,5],[5,5]])
b = np.array([[1,7],[2,7],[3,7],[4,7]])
c = combine(a,b)
```

Output:

```
[[  1.  nan   7.]
 [  2.   5.   7.]
 [  3.   5.   7.]
 [  4.  nan   7.]
 [  5.   5.  nan]]
```